# Bad Merge Conflict Resolution in Git. Retry bad commit, keeping changes since?

Tags: git, merge, git-extensions, merge-conflict-resolution

I'm working on a small project with one other developer and we're having a bit of a situation. We're both familiar with SVN, but Git is new to the both of us.

We're working on a single branch in our repository, each working on different aspects of our project.

What happened was he commit something, then I commit something, had conflicts (In designer files, as it tried to put both of our new files in the same "spot"), and as I resolved them, I must have missed something but now it's not working. I managed to somehow get the files into a working state, and continued on my merry way, adding more things that aren't affected by the bad conflict resolution.

So it looks like.

A(Good) -> B(Bad) -> C(Trying to fix) -> D(Revert Bad commit) -> A -> E (Completely new files) -> F(Completely new files) -> G(Other dev first commit since big problem, introduces more problems and conflicts.)

What I want to do basically, is go back to A. and merge in my B, E, and F commits, at which point the other dev can commit G. At this point I don't know what happened between B and E, so I'd rather just ditch it, as it was just me trying to resolve the problem. However, when I go back to A, I don't get prompted for the same conflicts I did when I originally committed B.

Please god help me.

Comment: What do you mean by "when I go back to A"? Are you doing `git reset A`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try checking out to your A commit by using the SHA reference, create a new branch from A and cherry pick B, E and F by using the cherry-pick command in git.

```
git checkout -f A23FDE (A)
git checkout -b new-branch-name
git cherry-pick F45HJ2 (B)
git cherry-pick E49FG2 (E)
git cherry-pick K83D87 (F)
```

Comment: This worked FANTASTICALLY! Took a little while, due to the kinds of merging errors we were encountering, but it definitely got us back to where we wanted to be with a working project.

My only other question is, now that we merged branch "CherryPick" into branch "master" how can we push this to origin/master and origin/HEAD without Git complaining? Where we are with master is exactly where we want those two to be...Reset? Rebase? We've tried reading but a reset is just a commit --amend? It's all so confusing haha. Thank you for your help!

Comment: If you have merged CherryPick into master and you are happy with the state of master then you should just be able to 'git push origin master'. If master is ahead or behind then you will have to 'git pull origin master' first and resolve any conflicts locally before pushing. If you want your local master branch to overwrite origin then just use the force flag on your push to origin master. Although I wouldn't recommend this as you should never really force updates on remote repos.